# executing shell command PHP and raspberry pi

Tags: php, gpio

I am following : http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple- ... ur-Raspbe/

The objective is to switch ON and OFF Pins as guided in tutorial But
here i am not able to use : system(),exec() as it does not execute 
commands in raspberry pi. Page is getting loaded accurately but when i 
press buttons only image changes(ON/OFF) but no execution of commands. 
I have well connected relays for my desired GPIO pin numbers 
I am using Tools : PHP,Javascript,Lighttpd webserver and my device is Pi 3 model B with raspian Jessie installed.

So i have decided to use " shell_exec " to execute commands but after implementing it into
program there is no effect in my prgram and it displays nothing. Need help where i am doing wrong.

```
gpio.php

    <?php
    //This page is requested by the JavaScript, it updates the pin's status and then print it
    //Getting and using values

    $pin = array(4,17,18,27,22,23,24,25);

    if (isset ( $_GET["pic"] )) {
            $pic = strip_tags ($_GET["pic"]);

            //test if value is a number
            if ( (is_numeric($pic)) && ($pic <= 7) && ($pic >= 0) ) {

                    //set the gpio's mode to output
                    shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode $pin[$pic] out");
                    //reading pin's status
                    shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g read $pin[$pic] $status $return ");
                    //set the gpio to high/low
                    if ($status[0] == "0" ) { $status[0] = "1"; }
                    else if ($status[0] == "1" ) { $status[0] = "0"; }
                    shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write $pin[$pic] $status[0]");
                    //reading pin's status
                    shell_exec ("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g read $pin[$pic] $status $return");
                    //print it to the client on the response
                    echo($status[0]);

            }
            else { echo ("fail"); }
    } //print fail if cannot use values
    else { echo ("fail"); }
    ?>

index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--TheFreeElectron 2015, http://www.instructables.com/member/TheFreeElectron/ -->

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Raspberry Pi Gpio</title>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color: black;">
    <!-- On/Off button's picture -->
    <?php
    $val_array = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    $pin = array(4,17,18,27,22,23,24,25);
    //this php script generate the first page in function of the file
    for ( $i= 0; $i<8; $i++) {
        //set the pin's mode to output and read them
        shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode $pin[$pic] out");
        shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g read $i, $val_array[$i],$status $return ");
    }
    //for loop to read the value
    $i =0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        //if off
        if ($val_array[$i][0] == 0 ) {
            echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/red/red_".$i.".jpg' onclick='change_pin (".$i.");'/>");
        }
        //if on
        if ($val_array[$i][0] == 1 ) {
            echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/green/green_".$i.".jpg' onclick='change_pin (".$i.");'/>");
        }    
    }
    ?>

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks 
Atila

Comment: Please attach proper links and format question properly

Comment: is `$status` an array? If so, as written, it breaks your `shell_exec` string

Comment: yes it is . i know i am doing some mistake in reading pins i guess :(

Comment: I don't know anything about that, but if its an array `$status $return");` is wrong you want something like `$status[0] $return");`